# Parse clicked image URL to form field

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

I am using fancybox to display a contact form (inline) in a modal window. The trigger for this form is when an image is clicked - what I would like to do if possible is to have the clicked image url entered into one of the form fields but am unsure how i go about doing so? I presume this is possible by storing the clicked image URL in a variable then calling it into the msg field?

Comment: [What have you tried so far?](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: $("#storefront img").click(function() {
  console.log($("img", this).attr("src"));

but this does not seem to log any clicked images

Answer (score 0):

As part of your trigger, you can get the src of the image with [prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) and store it in a variable like this:

```
var clickedImageURL;

$("body").on("click", "img", function() {
  clickedImageURL = $(this).prop("src");
  // do whatever else your function does
});
```

Then, you can set the value of any input by targeting it and using [val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/), like:

```
$("your-input-field").val(clickedImageURL);
```

An example of it being used:
http://codepen.io/jonathanrbowman/pen/pjLZBB

Comment: i'm getting Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token } with your code, but can't see the problem myself?

Comment: I added a codepen to show it in action, hopefully that can help clarify usage.

Comment: your example works beautifully however it does nothing on my page frustratingly (fixed the syntax error). Will keep playing to see if I can get it to work. Thanks for your help. At the moment i'm trying: $("body").on("click", "img", function() {
  clickedImageURL = $(this).prop("src");
  alert(clickedImageURL);
}); but I get no alert

Comment: Did you define clickedImageURL as a variable?

Comment: I did:
var clickedImageURL;
$("body").on("click", "img", function() {
  clickedImageURL = $(this).prop("src");
  alert(clickedImageURL);
});

 $(".modaltowbartrigger").fancybox({
 'scrolling'  : 'no',
 'titleShow'  : false
});

The modalbox works still..

Comment: Console log $(this) inside the function and make sure you're getting the element you're expecting. I would still think it show an alert, though.

Comment: still nothing, strange!

Comment: Also, as you go along and adjust your code, please update your original question to include code and maintain it as your solution evolves. This will help keep things organized and inform others as to what road you're currently on.

Answer (score 0):

Having an html like :

```
<a class="fancybox" href="images/image01.jpg"><img src="thumbs/thiumb01.jpg" alt=""/></a>
```

... you could use a fancybox *callback* to populate the form field with the value of the `href` attribute of the anchor above. The only thing you may need is the selector of that form field you want to populate with, so you could do :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $(".fancybox").fancybox({
        // API options
        type: "inline",
        href: "#myform",
        beforeShow: function () {
            $("#myform").find(".inputURL").val($(this.element).attr("href"))
        }
    }); // fancybox
}); // ready
```

Notice the selector `#myform` is the ID of your form and the selector `.inputURL` is a *class* name of your form field. Also notice we changed the `type` to `inline` since we intend to open an *inline* form (for illustration purposes) and not the actual image in fancybox. Of course, we have also changed the `href` option to target the form instead of the image.

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/2r7zxrsd/)**